# Locating numerical errors due to Integer division

Tags: c++, integer-division

Is there a g++ warning or other tool that can identify integer division (truncation toward zero)?  I have thousands of lines of code with calculations that inevitably will have numerical errors typically due to "float = int/int" that need to be located.  I need a reasonable method for finding these.

Comment: Are there any OS restrictions? (for static analysis tool recommendations).

Comment: Currently using Debian 5.06 and likely 6.01 in the near future.

Comment: I use gcc and I wasn't able to find any warning that will catch this ` double alpha = 4/9/M_PI;`. I tried `-Wall`, `-Wextra` and `-Wconversion`. Expressions involving floats and integer division should give warning in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Try `-Wconversion`.

From gcc's man page:

> Warn for implicit conversions that may
>   alter a value. This includes
>   conversions between real and integer,
>   like "abs (x)" when "x" is "double";
>   conversions between signed and
>   unsigned, like "unsigned ui = -1"; and
>   conversions to smaller types, like
>   "sqrtf (M_PI)". Do not warn for
>   explicit casts like "abs ((int) x)"
>   and "ui = (unsigned) -1", or if the
>   value is not changed by the conversion
>   like in "abs (2.0)".  Warnings about
>   conversions between signed and
>   unsigned integers can be disabled by
>   using -Wno-sign-conversion.
>
> For C++, also warn for conversions
>   between "NULL" and non-pointer types;
>   confusing overload resolution for
>   user-defined conversions; and
>   conversions that will never use a type
>   conversion operator: conversions to
>   "void", the same type, a base class or
>   a reference to them. Warnings about
>   conversions between signed and
>   unsigned integers are disabled by
>   default in C++ unless
>   -Wsign-conversion is explicitly enabled.

For the following sample program (`test.cpp`), I get the error `test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:7: warning: conversion to ‘float’ from ‘int’ may alter its value`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
    float f = a / b;

    std::cout << f;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this warning before, but unfortunately there are so many implicit conversions in the code that it isn't feasible to pick out the ones related to integer division.  I need to address the numerical errors prior to doing any kind of code cleanup that would allow Wconversion to be useful in this case.

Comment: If you have that many conversion errors, why don't you just pipe them through `grep` and filter on `float`?

Answer (score 2):

I have a hard time calling these numerical errors.  You asked for integer calculations, and got the correct numbers for integer calculations.  If those numbers aren't acceptable, then ask for floating point calculations:

```
int x = 3;
int y = 10;

int z = x / y;

// "1." is the same thing as "1.0", you may want to read up on
// "the usual arithmetic conversions."  You could add some
// parentheses here, but they aren't needed for this specific
// statement.
double zz = 1. * x / y;
```

Comment: Yes, exactly.  They would more accurately be called "incorrect type choice" than numerical errors.

Answer (score 1):

[This page contains info about g++ warnings.  If you've already tried `-Wall` then the only thing left could be the warnings in this link.  On second look `-Wconversion` might do the trick.](http://docs.freebsd.org/info/gcc/gcc.info.Warning_Options.html)

Note: Completely edited the response.

Comment: Overloading an operator involving only primitive types is illegal; i.e., the overload must involve at least one UDT.

Answer (score 1):

### Remark on [`-Wconversion`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wclobbered-421) of [gcc](http://www.gcc.org):

Changing the type of the floating point variable from `float` to `double` makes the warning vanish:

```
$ cat 'file.cpp'

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int a = 2;
   int b = 3;
   double f = a / b;

   std::cout << f;
}
```

Compiling with `$ g++-4.7 -Wconversion 'file.cpp'` returns no warnings (as `$ clang++ -Weverything 'file.cpp'`).

### Explanation:

The warning when using the type `float` is not returned because of the totally valid integer arithmetics, but because `float` cannot store all possible values of `int` (larger ones cannot be captured by `float` but by `double`). So  there might be a change of value when assigning RHS to `f` in the case of float but not in the case of double. To make it clear: The warning is not returned because of `int/int` but because of the assignment `float = int`.

For this see following questions: [what the difference between the float and integer data type when the size is same in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806944/what-the-difference-between-the-float-and-integer-data-type-when-the-size-is-sam), [Storing ints as floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149992/storing-ints-as-floats) and [Rounding to use for int -> float -> int round trip conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883385/rounding-to-use-for-int-float-int-round-trip-conversion)

However, when using `float` `-Wconversion` could still be useful to identify possible lines which are affected but is not comprehensive and is actually not intended for that. For the purpose of `-Wconversion` see [docs/gcc/Warning-Options.html](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wclobbered-421) and here [gcc.gnu.org/wiki/NewWconversion](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/NewWconversion)

Possibly of interest is also following discussion '[Implicit casting Integer calculation to float in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449578/implicit-casting-integer-calculation-to-float-in-c)'

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find such error is to have really good unit tests. All alternatives are not good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [clang-tidy detection](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/bugprone-integer-division.html).

It catches cases like this:

```
d = 32 * 8 / (2 + i);
d = 8 * floatFunc(1 + 7 / 2);
d = i / (1 << 4);
```