# Why is (1/2)*x different from 0.5*x?

Tags: c++, c

This behaves as wanted:

```
double t = r[1][0] * .5;
```

But this doesn't:

```
double t = ((1/2)*r[1][0]);
```

`r` is a 2-D Vector.

Just thought of a possibility. Is it because (`1/2`) is considered an `int` and `(1/2) == 0`?

Comment: Why is a basic problem about integer vs float types being voted up?

Comment: Not only basic, but the OP already had the answer but didn't try it. Votes are so random in SO...

Comment: It's getting extra eyeballs because it is a "hot question" in StackExchange. Extra eyeballs = extra votes.

Comment: "Votes are so random in SO" I would go further, votes are 99% bonkers in SO (but it's still fun).

Comment: 6 upvotes for a silly question. I cant believe this!!

Comment: @tbert: because people don't care enough to (re)search the topic online or read good books on C(++), let alone the language standard?

Comment: Indeed; this question has 23 upvotes and gained the poster 2 badges.

Comment: try `((1/2)/*r[1][0])` :)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

> Is it because (1/2) is considered an int and (1/2) == 0?

Yes, both of those literals are of type `int`, therefore the result will be of type `int`, and that result is 0.

Instead, make one of those literals a `float` or `double` and you'll end up with the floating point result of `0.5`, ie:

`double t = ((1.0/2)*r[1][0]);`

Because `1.0` is of type `double`, the `int` 2 will be promoted to a `double` and the result will be a `double`.

Answer (score 14):

Write this instead:

```
  double t = ((1/2.0)*r[1][0]);
```

`1 / 2` is an integer division and the result is `0`.

`1 / 2.0` is a floating point division (with `double` values after the usual arithmetic conversions) and its result is `0.5`.

Answer (score 6):

Because `1/2` is `int`/`int` division. That means whatever is the result will have anything after the decimal point removed (truncated). So `1/2` = 0.5 = 0.

Normally I always write the first number in `double` : `1.0/2` …..

If you make the very first number a `double` then all remaining calculation is done in `double` only.

Comment: Doesn't have to be *the first number*, just one of them at least.

Comment: Just make a habit of using first number as float then you won't run into surprises. Another good habit is to start with 1.0 * ....

Comment: Note that in `2.0 * x + (7 / 5)`, the first number is a `double` and the OP's issue is still present.

Comment: You're right, but this is the best we can do to minimize such issues.

Answer (score 2):

```
double t = r[1][0] * .5;
```

is equivalent to:

```
double t = ((1/2f)*r[1][0]);
```

and not:

```
double t = ((1/2)*r[1][0]);
```

Due to loss of decimal part when the temporary result of 1/2 is stored in an `int` variable.

As a guideline whenever there is a division and there is a possibility of the answer being real number, do not use `int` or make one of the operands `float` or `double` or use *cast*.

Answer (score 1):

You can write 1.0/2.0 instead.  1/2 displays this behaviour because both the denominator and numerator act are of an integer type and a variable of an integer type divided by another variable of an integer type is always truncated to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot merit or demerit the standard of the question but this seem very critical issue to me. We assume that compiler will do the laundry for us all the time , but [that is not true](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-programming/eight-c-programming-mistakes-the-compiler-wont-catch/) some times.

Is there any way to avoid this situation ?

[Possibly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076878/locating-numerical-errors-due-to-integer-division)

OR

More importantly knowing the monster (`C`,`C++`) as most of the people  point out above

I would like to know if there are other ways to  trace these "truncation" issues at compile time